# Unbiasedness of MoM estimator

Tags: econometrics

Why is the method of moments estimator $g(\bar{Y})$ of $\theta$ only unbiased if $g(\mu)$ is a linear function of $\mu$?  (Note: It is assumed that $\theta=g(\mu)$ for some function $g$ and $\bar{Y}$ is a consistent and unbiased estimator of $\mu$)

I'm working in Appendix C (p.685) in the 6th edition of Wooldridge's *Introductory Econometrics*.  Many thanks in advance for helping me develop an intuition.

Comment: $E[g(\bar{Y})] \neq \theta$, in general, when $g$ is nonlinear.

Comment: Though not necessary, to add just a little more to Michael's comment, $E[g(\bar{Y})] \ne g(E[\bar{Y}]) = g(\mu) = \theta$ in general if $g$ is nonlinear.